# How to define the user-extensions.js with maven-selenium-plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, selenium

Does anyone knows how to set the default user extension with the maven-selenium-plugin ?
I tested almost everything. My user-extensions.js is in '**src/test/resources/**' and the plugin always take the extension in '**target/selenium**'...

I tried this :
< defaultUserExtensionEnabled>true< /defaultUserExtensionEnabled>
< defaultUserExtension>**src/test/resources/user-extensions.js**< /defaultUserExtension>

This still doesn't work. Can someone help me using those tags ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ok... I'm really dumb.
Using < userExtensions> works a lot better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I think it works. Please take a better look at target/selenium/user-extensions.js

The userExtensions param specify the "Location of the user-extensions.js to load into the server. If defaultUserExtensionsEnabled is true, then this file will be **appended** to the defaults."

However, if you don't want to have the default user extension, if think you must set false

Comment: Well I knew it doesn't work, because my tests failed (needed scLocator). But I'm dumb. Sorry for posting here, I jsut made a mistake.
In fact it's not < defaultUserExtension> but < defaultUserExtension**s**> 
And there is something else :
< userExtensions>< /userExtensions> which allow to define the custom user-extensions.js

Thanks for your help :D